# jquery - how could prevent clicked link when I move links with drag&drop?

Tags: jquery

I allow move (drag&drop) some elements which contains inside link (`a`), After user drop it, it redirects browser to `href` of moved element. How could I allow to click that element and drag&drop its also?
I use http://dragsort.codeplex.com/ plugin.

Comment: Try to use div as container of the link and drag & drop the div not the link.

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI `draggable()` for this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You'd prevent the default behaviour from being actioned on links, buttons and the like by using `preventDefault()`;

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
         // Do some stuff when you've finished dragging your element
         event.preventDefault(); }
});
```

Check the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do call event.preventDefault() when you want the default action to be skipped.  It's up to you to figure out if the item was being dragged and so should not be navigated, -vs- a standard click.  But assuming you store a flag in data, it might look something like this:

```
$('.something').click(function(event) { 
    if ($(this).data('dragging')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).data('dragging',false);
    }
}
```